# Commercial Vendors for Risk Management and Portfolio Optimization and Performance Attribution

Tags: risk-management, portfolio-optimization

So this question is directly about companies such as Axioma, Barra, Northfield, and etc. that provide risk management, portfolio optimization, and performance attribution related services. I want to get a feel to the extent that investment banks, asset management firms, and hedge funds use these types of services. I know the answer is going to be it varies. However, I would appreciate it if anyone can shed more light as to the extent of use and reasons for their limitations. Does everybody or do most divisions have access to these vendors? I understand cost is a reason, but what would else would prevent institutions from using it. I really would like to know more of their limitations from a practitioner point of view, because from what I understand they have a wealth of information and a diverse array of factors to understand and dissect the drivers of risk and return, relating it to exposure.